# How to Interpret output Coefficients of Linear Support Vector Regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, svm, kernel-trick

I'm looking to interpret the output from my SVR model.

I know that with SVM you can't directly interpret the coefficients of the model but that you first have to take a dot product

With that said, how would one interpret the coefficients of a `linear` kernel SVR model? Hence, once I've obtained the coefficients vector, what transformation do I need to apply and how would I go about interpreting the results?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you've trained an SVR model in the dual using a linear kernel, so that your predictive function is
$$
f(x) = \sum_i \alpha_i k(X_i, x) + b
$$
and
$$
k(x, y) = x^\top y
,$$
then you can find the coefficients in each dimension like so:
\begin{align}
     f(x)
  &= \sum_i \alpha_i X_i^\top x + b
   = \left( \sum_i \alpha_i X_i \right)^\top x + b
\end{align}
so that
$$
f(x) = w^\top x + b
\qquad
w = \sum_i \alpha_i X_i
.$$